# With Python or Pandas, extract only the strings from a txt or dat-file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract, file-read

I have a .dat-file with the following shape and being a few hundred lines long:

```
AlOH                 200  6000  1000
 7.882068110E+05 -2.263671626E+03  7.823954880E+00  1.821171456E-04 -8.263729320E-08  1.265414876E-11 -6.875972530E-16 -1.039808093E+04 -2.209032458E+01
 5.876493180E+04 -9.449422690E+02  7.820599180E+00  5.858888470E-04 -4.083666810E-06  4.587229340E-09 -1.563936726E-12 -1.993283011E+04 -2.065043885E+01
Al2O                 200  6000  1000
-1.171074351E+05 -1.783009166E+02  7.633215360E+00 -5.335931770E-05  1.180702791E-08 -1.355444579E-12  6.287323890E-17 -1.947580149E+04 -1.415764167E+01
 7.776530700E+03 -1.294235361E+02  4.912509520E+00  8.604223450E-03 -1.217703648E-05  8.314634870E-09 -2.237722201E-12 -1.886512879E+04 -2.806368311E-02
Al2O3                200  6000  1000
-2.777784969E+05 -4.917465930E+02  1.386703888E+01 -1.469381940E-04  3.250406490E-08 -3.730867350E-12  1.730444284E-16 -6.790757850E+04 -4.375559873E+01
-7.443374320E+03  8.829004210E+01  5.264662640E+00  2.507678848E-02 -3.434541650E-05  2.302516980E-08 -6.122529280E-12 -6.872685950E+04  2.202324298E+00
```

I want to extract only the chemical names (so only the strings) from it, preferably into a list like `[AlOH, Al2O, Al2O3, ...]`. I tried to do this with pandas, but due to the strange format of the columns the file is not being properly read. I haven't found on the internet any other solution that would be short and simple, though this should have a nice pythonic solution.

Has any one a solution how to extract only the strings?

---

**Suggested solution:**

```
chemicals = []
with open('bla_file.dat') as file:
    for line in file: 
        line = line.split()
        for item in line:
            try:
                float(item)
            except ValueError:
                chemicals.append(item)
```

Please post any solutions that might be simpler or shorter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use list comprehensions for creating the chemicals headers and regular expressions for matching its names:

```
with open('bla_file.dat') as f:

    chemicals = [re.findall('^\w+',line)[0] for line in f.readlines() if re.search('^\w+',line)]
```

On the example you showed it returns:

`['AlOH', 'Al2O', 'Al2O3']`

In this example you are simply matching the pattern desired for the chemicals names on each line and adding it to a list if matched. But you still have to read line by line for creating the list.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed short. What do `re.findall('^\w+',line)` and `re.search('^\w+',line)` do? How is their function to be understood?

Comment: The `re.findall(pattern, string)` returns a list with all the matches of the pattern inside the string. The `re.search(pattern, string)` returns only an object if the pattern is matched inside the string, hence it's more used as a condition (`if`). The pattern `^\w+` searchs at the beginning of the string (`^`) any word character (`\w`). The quantifier `+` tells to search at least one or more of this preceding token (word character). For further information please take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

Start with parsing then either select stings you want or deselect unwanted based on characters or data type.

example deselecting based on characters in unwanted strings:

```
nstr = ['.','+','-']

for line in lines:
    str = line.split(' ')

    for str in line:
        if str.findall(nstr):
            continue
        else
            print str
```

Comment: Thanks! Eventually I solved a problem in a similar way, but with using deselecting not based on characters, but based if the string is convertible to float. I added the solution to my question, but maybe somebody can paste a shorter and simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading it in as a list then:

```
lst = [1,5,'Chemical1', 1.05543, 'Chemical2']
chemLst = []
for x in lst:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        chemLst.append(x)
```

or

```
chemLst = [i for i in lst if isinstance(i, str)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am TRYING to read them as a list, but I don't know how to do it. I am currently reading as `with open('bla.dat') as file:`, and I don't know how most efficiently to continue. I think there might be a better way with pandas

Comment: something like: `data = []`  `for row in file: data.append(row.split(" "))` then run the above code? Somthing like that.  But if you could get it nicly into a pandas dataframe that would be the best. The you just extract the headers using head  = list(df)